# django - clean dynamic field

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_type = models.ForeignKey(OrderType)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

I added the form filed dynamically:

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = [
            'order_type', 'product'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'order_type': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'product': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, types=[],*args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if "AMOUNT" in types:
            self.fields['quantity'] = IntegerField(
                NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
            )
```

And in `CreateView` I overwrite post. In the frontend I'm sending ajax with data or not (if data is sent, I want to generate form with addition quantity field), then I replace the old form with this new:

```
class OrderCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Order
    form_class = OrderForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        d = request.POST.get('DATA', None)
        if d is not None:

            form = self.form_class(
                types=["AMOUNT"],
                **self.kwargs
            )
            return render(
                request, 'form.html', {'form': form}
            )
        else:
            form = self.form_class(**self.kwargs)
            return render(
                request, 'form.html', {'form': form}
            )
        return super(OrderCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And it "works". I get new form with a quantity. But when I'm trying do submit this form, I get an error

```
null value in column "quantity" violates not-null constraint
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last line of your post method is unreachable. Post function will never go here:

```
return super(OrderCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I suppose you need to change logic of your code. For example if it possible instead of sending 'DATA' with POST try to send it with GET. Or create another view to render form with 'AMOUNT' field.

**UPDATE**

Also please note that `super().post()` calls [get_form()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L39) which return default instance of form_class. Considering this `super().post()` probably is not what you really need. Try to perform form validation and form saving manually:

```
form = self.form_class(
        types=["AMOUNT"],
        **self.kwargs
    )
if form.is_valid():
    instance = self.form.save()
    return super().get()
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. I changed def post to def get, and in post method only add print request.post and return super. And when I submit the form. I can see quantity field in print request post, but it's gone in form_valid method in createview (print form.cleaned_data)

Comment: Ok, i've just overload get_form method. I don't know if it is 'right way' but it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In your model try to change

```
quantity = models.IntegerField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)
```

to

```
quantity = models.IntegerField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4, null=True, blank=True)
```

Whenever you don't have the flag "AMOUNT" it tries to create an Order without filling that field.

UPDATE: 
Try this in your form

```
fields = [
        'order_type', 'product', 'quantity'
    ]
widgets = {
        'order_type': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'product': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'quantity': NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    }
def __init__(self, types=[],*args, **kwargs):
    super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if "AMOUNT" not in types:
        del self.fields['quantity']
```

In your view put the `super()` before as @neverwalkaloner mentioned

Comment: Now I don't have quantity in clean method.